# Change EF6 key FK convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, naming-conventions

EF by default name my FKs as `EntityName_id` and I would like it to be named `id_EntityName`. How can I do that?

**Edit1:**
There are over 700 FKs here... automate this would be a lot faster I belive... Also intend to use the same answer to normalize composite PKs...

Comment: MSDN has an example of creating a custom ForeignKeyNamingConvention here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439.aspx#example2 ... I haven't tried this but it might be something you could build on.

Comment: @Peter thank you! worked perfectly! would you mind posting as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great! Feel free to update my answer (or post and accept your own answer) with the code that worked for you. I'm sure it would be useful for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN has an example of creating a custom ForeignKeyNamingConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439.aspx#example2). You could modify this example to name the Foreign Keys according to your convention.

I haven't tested this, but here's some rough code that you might be able to build on:

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
    {
        if (association.IsForeignKey)
        {
            var constraint = association.Constraint;

            for (int i = 0; i < constraint.ToProperties.Count; ++i)
            {
                int underscoreIndex = constraint.ToProperties[i].Name.IndexOf('_');
                if (underscoreIndex > 0)
                {
                    // change from EntityName_Id to id_EntityName
                    constraint.ToProperties[i].Name = "id_" + constraint.ToProperties[i].Name.Remove(underscoreIndex);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register your custom convention in your `DbContext's` `OnModelCreating()` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{  
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ForeignKeyNamingConvention>();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to use fluent mapping, for instance

```
.Map(m => m.MapKey("id_EntityName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through setting up the mappings for your entities.

```
public class User
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Address Address {get;set;}


}

public class Address
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     //Some other properties
}




public class UserMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
         HasOptional(u => u.Address).WithMany()
                                   .Map(m => m.MapKey("Id_Address"));

    }
}

//Override the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuild.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping());
}
```